# How to get a value of a funktion without re-running it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-value

Hey I actually just started with python and I have a question:
How can i use a variable from an function(a) in another function(b) without re-running the function(a) (like with "return" usw.)?
here is my code:

```
def SubmitVocab():
        RandomNum = GetNum()
        print(RandomNum)




def GetNum():
    RandomNum = randint(1, 10)
    if RandomNum % 2:
        pass
    else:
        RandomNum = RandomNum - 1
    print(RandomNum)

    return RandomNum

GetNum()
SubmitVocab()
```

I want to have the same number two time and not to different generated numbers
Hope you get it! Thanks for answering

Comment: you have two functions, which are you looking to get the random number from

Comment: Assign the result of the function call to a variable, as you do with `RandomNum = randint(...)`.

Comment: Then you save the value from the first call and re-use it.  This is exactly what variables do.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: I want to get it from the second funktion

Comment: i changed some stuff, i hope its more clear now

Answer (score 0):

In first function

```
SubmitVocab.RandomNum = NextVocab()
print(SubmitVocab.RandomNum)
```

By this way you can use its variable in other function.
As in Python, everything can act as an object.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: That didnt help. idk why, i wrote it like you sad but its still gicing me two diffrent numbers. wasnt youre fault, i made a mistake when sharing my code

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself...
you can just solve it with global variables

so it would be:

```
RandomNum2 = 0

    def SubmitVocab():
        print(RandomNum2)


    def GetNum():
        RandomNum = randint(1, 10)
        if RandomNum % 2:
            pass
        else:
            RandomNum = RandomNum - 1
        global RandomNum2
        RandomNum2 = RandomNum
        print(RandomNum)


GetNum()
SubmitVocab()
```